# table cells have too much space between them

Tags: html, css, html-table

Ok, so I have several problems with this table. I need it to look like as lose as possible to this:

[image: Table]

However, when I try to achieve this, there ends up being a ton of space between the table cells that contain the text and for some reason valign="top" is not working nor is vertical-align:middle for the text portions so they don't line up with the top of the image. This is what it looks like right now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mqbze.jpg

Not sure how to fix any of this or get it to look like the original. :( Please help! Thanks in advance!!!

```
<table width="570" align="center" style="padding-top:10px; background-color:#FFF; border-top:dotted 1px #000;">
 <tr>
 <td width="190" valign="top">
  <img src="images/plant.jpg" />
 </td>
<td width="199" valign="top" style="vertical-align:top;">
<p style="font-size:14px; color:#646f9a; line-height:15px;">DEFYING THE RECESSION<br>
<span style="font-size:11px; color:#707764; line-height:12px; letter-spacing:0.2pt;"><strong>Sarah Walker</strong>, CNNMoney.com staff writer</span></p>
<p style="font-size:11px; color:#707764; line-height:12px; letter-spacing:0.2pt;">When metal worker Ken Kash was laid off in July from his job at a theatre set company, he decided not to look for another full-time position. Instead, he's pursing a <span style="text-decoration:underline;">longtime dream</span>: launching his own company.</p>
<p style="font-size:11px; color:#646f9a;">STRATEGIC <strong>INVESTMENT</strong> <span style="color:#c0d84d;">&bull;</span></p>
 </td>
 <td width="121" valign="top" rowspan="1" style="background-color:#eff2d9; border-bottom:solid #c0d84d 8px; padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px; padding-top:2px;">
 <p style="font-size:14px; color:#646f9a; line-height:15px;">ASK AN EXPERT</p>
 <p style="font-size:11px; color:#707764; line-height:12px; letter-spacing:0.2pt;"><strong>Q: Is there anything in this massive federal economic stimulus plan for small business? <br>
 — Rick<br><br>

 A: Yes, lots.</strong><br><br>

  There is going to be a lot of federal, state and local money available. Get ready to take advantage of it. <span style="text-decoration:underline;">Read more...</span></p>
 <p style="font-size:11px; color:#646f9a;">ASK THE <strong>EXPERT</strong> <span style="color:#c0d84d;">&bull;</span></p>
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td valign="top" style="vertical-align:top;"><img src="images/video.jpg" />
 </td>
 <td valign="top" style="vertical-align:top;">
 <p style="font-size:14px; color:#646f9a; line-height:15px;">DEFYING THE RECESSION<br>
 <span style="font-size:11px; color:#707764; line-height:12px; letter-spacing:0.2pt;"><strong>Sarah Walker</strong>, CNNMoney.com staff writer</span></p>
 <p style="font-size:11px; color:#707764; line-height:12px; letter-spacing:0.2pt;">When metal worker Ken Kash was laid off in July from his job at a theatre set company, he decided not to look for another full-time position. Instead, he's pursing a <span style="text-decoration:underline;">longtime dream</span>: launching his own company.</p>
 <p style="font-size:11px; color:#646f9a;">STRATEGIC <strong>INVESTMENT</strong> <span style="color:#c0d84d;">&bull;</span></p>
</td>
<td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: You shouldn't use table for this. Use flexbox, float, or inline-block (google them).

Comment: Use CSS classes. Rowspan is set to 1. Double that up.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that this is for email so tables have to be used because divs, etc are not displayed properly across ESPs.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldnt be using tables for that. Try twitter bootstrap or 960 Gs or sny other css grid system.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that this is for email so tables have to be used because divs, etc are not displayed properly across ESPs.